# Bind Access form to the results from a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures

I am trying to return the results of a stored procedure to a form. I have managed to iterate thru the results using an ADO recordset, but cannot bind the results to the form..

Here is the VBA code:

```
Private Sub RetrieveSiteInformation()

  Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
  Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset, f As ADODB.Field

  With cnn
    .Provider = "SQLOLEDB"
    .ConnectionString = 
        "data source=UKFCSVR;initial catalog=ACACB;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
    .Open
  End With

  Dim param1  As ADODB.Parameter
  If Nz(txtSiteID_Search.Value, vbNullString) <> vbNullString Then
    Set param1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@SiteID", adBigInt, adParamInput)
    param1.Value = txtSiteID_Search.Value
    cmd.Parameters.Append param1
  End If

  With cmd
   .ActiveConnection = cnn
   .CommandText = "spSiteInformation_Retrieve"
   .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    **' THIS FAILS**
    Me.Recordset = .Execute
    **' THIS LOOP WORKS FINE**
    '    Set rs = .Execute
    '    rs.MoveFirst
    '    For Each f In rs.Fields
    '      Debug.Print f.Name
    '    Next
    '    With rs
    '      Do While Not .EOF
    '        Debug.Print ![CompanyName] & " " & ![Postcode]
    '        .MoveNext
    '      Loop
    '    End With
  End With
  cnn.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I have tested this example. It includes changes to suit my set-up which I have left in, rather than guessing at your set-up. Most of this is taken from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281998/EN-US/

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim param1  As New ADODB.Parameter

    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0"
        .Properties("Data Provider").Value = "SQLOLEDB"
        .Properties("Data Source").Value = "Server"
        .Properties("Integrated Security").Value = "SSPI"
        .Properties("Initial Catalog").Value = "Test"
        .Open
    End With

    txtSiteID_Search = 1

    If Nz(txtSiteID_Search, vbNullString) <> vbNullString Then
        Set param1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@SiteID", adBigInt, adParamInput)
        param1.Value = txtSiteID_Search
        cmd.Parameters.Append param1
    End If

    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = cn
        .CommandText = "spSiteInformation_Retrieve"
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        Set Me.Recordset = .Execute
    End With
```

Comment: Remou: Nice, I did not think you could use an ADO rs as the form recordsource. FMY, is there any benefit compared to the PTQ solution I proposed ?

Comment: @iDevelop I am not at all sure, but there are things you can do with ADO that you cannot do with DAO. There are advantages to using both ADO and DAO, so it is often a good idea to set up Access to use both. Also, I think pass-through queries use ODBC, but OLEDB may offer better performance (http://database.ittoolbox.com/documents/odbc-vs-oledb-18150)

Answer (score 2):

Forget ADO. Create a passthru query in Access, with property `ReturnsRecords = True`.
Bind your form to that passthru query.
Using VBA, change the .SQL property of that QueryDef object, then open the form. You're done.

```
Set qry = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("myQryDef")
qry.SQL = "exec spMyStoredProc " & "'argument1'"
```

Comment: the project is currently an mdb.. and i'm migrating the backend to SQL 2005.. i'd like to keep it as an mdb if possible..

surely it can be done in ADO ?

Comment: with mdb you normally use DAO (well...I do). My solution is for an mdb. Once you've opened the form, you can then use Me.RecordsetClone if you want. But be aware that that WILL give you a DAO recordset, NOT ADO.

Comment: Access is more friendly to DAO recordsets, as that's its native data interface. ADO was grafted on in the A2000 time frame, and was not a good fit. It has a number of problems, in fact. If you're using ODBC linked tables, you're going through Jet/ACE, so you would want to use DAO on any linked tables. Passthrough bypasses the Jet/ACE query optimizer, but is still passed through Jet/ACE and ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Set` whenever you assign an object reference in VBA.

Change `Me.Recordset = .Execute` to `Set Me.Recordset = .Execute`.

Also, you probably need to open it with a supported cursor type. I don't think there's a way to change the cursor type if you use the Execute method on the Command object. You'll have to create the Recordset separately.

```
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open cmd, , adOpenKeyset
Set Me.Recordset = rs
```

Comment: Run-time error '7965'

The object you entered is not a valid Recordset property.

Comment: I think Access forms require a DAO recordset, not ADO.

Comment: No, it supports ADO as well. The Recordset probably has the wrong cursor type.

Comment: Hi Tmdean

Tried your latest suggestion, but still get the same error: 

Run-time error '7965' The object you entered is not a valid Recordset property

I have double checked the table the SP pulls from and it has a primary key.. 

Have you got a working example of pulling results from an SP?

This is really frustrating..

Comment: For the record, I'm using ADO recordsets without a problem although I'm not getting them through stored procedures.